# Excel automation-record reponse

Tags: excel, outlook

I have an excel sheet which contains some data related to change management.

Users open excel sheet and provide their approval with comments recorded in a particular column.

Is there a way where we can trigger mail to people based on data in excel with approval /rejection link and record their response in the excel automatically?

I tried doing with webforms but was not of much help

Comment: Is there a way? Yes, there are many ways.  You might want to try breaking your your task down into a list of discrete steps and spend some time coming up with a rough idea of how you'll solve each.  Then identify the ones that are the most critical, the most challenging, and/or you know the least about; if you focus on those until you are certain of the solution then the rest will fall into place.  Alternatively, you can start with what you know you can accomplish, and then work towards the harder pieces; but you'll probably find yourself rewritting a lot more of your code this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop an Excel add-in where you can automate Outlook for sending emails and handling new emails. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-excel?view=vs-2019) to get started quickly. Or just automate Outlook from Excel VBA macros.

The [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/) article explains the required steps for sending emails programmatically:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// ...
private void CreateSendItem(Outlook.Application Application)
{
     Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
     Outlook.Recipients mailRecipients = null;
     Outlook.Recipient mailRecipient = null;
     try
     {
          mail = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
              as Outlook.MailItem;
          mail.Subject = "A programatically generated e-mail";
          mailRecipients = mail.Recipients;
          mailRecipient = mailRecipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev");
          mailRecipient.Resolve();
          if (mailRecipient.Resolved)
          {
              mail.Send();
          }
          else
          {
              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
                  "There is no such record in your address book.");
          }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
              "An exception is occured in the code of add-in.");
     }
     finally
     {
         if (mailRecipient != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailRecipient);
         if (mailRecipients != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailRecipients);
         if (mail != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);
     }
}
```